# Passing hashtable {} from javascript to mvc3 controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I pass the following back to an mmvc3 controller ActionResult?

```
var hashtable = {};
hashtable['screaming'] = ["1", "2"];
hashtable['mellow'] = ["3", "4", "5"];
$.get('@Url.Action("PerformMagic")', { 'theValues': hashtable }, function (data) {
    //Callback..    
});
```

What would my controller method sig look like?

```
public ActionResult PerformMagic(/*What type goes here? string[] theValues or string[][] theValues)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass the hashtable value to an action the most natural way would be to pass it as a dictionary to an action

```
public ActionResult PerformMagic(Dictionary<String, List<int>> theValues)
{
    // the magic!
}
```

When passing the values using jQuery Ajax functionality to the ASP.NET MVC action you're facing a big framework misunderstanding. The ASP.NET MVC ModelBinder expects values that should be bound to a Dictionary in the request body or URL using this naming scheme

```
theValues[0].key=key0
theValues[0].value[0]=values0.0
theValues[0].value[1]=values0.1
theValues[1].key=key1
theValues[1].value[0]=values1.0
theValues[1].value[1]=values1.1
theValues[1].value[2]=values1.2
```

[This blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) gives further detail about the ASP.NET MVC naming scheme for dictionaries and lists.

But jQuery uses this naming scheme to pass values in the request body or URL

```
theValues[key0][]=value0.0
theValues[key0][]=value0.1
theValues[key1][]=value1.0
theValues[key1][]=value1.1
theValues[key1][]=value1.2
```

In both examples I omitted the '&' and split the request values in separate lines for better readability.

So if you want to pass the values as a Dictionary to the action method you need to make jQuery and ASP.NET MVC Model Binders talk. I can think of two options:

1. Change the naming scheme that ASP.NET MVC expects for request
   parameters
2. Change the naming scheme that jQuery uses to build
   request parameters

Method 1 would require you to write your own Model Binder and since the naming functionality for binding to Dictionary action arguments is somewhere hidden in an internal *UpdateDictionary* method, writing your own Model Binder would imply to copy a lot of ASP.NET MVC DefaultModelBinder code...

Method 2 should be fairly simple to implement because jQuery uses the *param* function to build request parameters and the jQuery *ajax* function allows you to just pass in raw values that were transformed by a custom function to request parameters. More detail about jQuery ajax function can be [found here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). See section 'processData'.

I'll give a **prototype** jQuery implementation to pass the *hashtable* var as a dictionary parameter to an ASP.NET MVC controller action:

```
function buildParams(prefix, dict) {
    var s = [],
    add = function (key, value) {
        // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
        value = jQuery.isFunction(value) ? value() : value;
        s[s.length] = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    };

    var i = 0;

    jQuery.each(dict, function (key, values) {
        add(prefix + '[' + i + '].key', key);

        jQuery.each(values, function (j, value) {
            add(prefix + '[' + i + '].value[' + j + ']', value);
        });

        i++;
    });

    return s.join('&');
}

$(function () {
    $('#submithashes').click(function (e) {
        var hashtable2 = {};
        hashtable2['screaming'] = ["1", "2"];
        hashtable2['mellow'] = ["3", "4", "5"];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("PerformMagic")',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            data: buildParams('theValues', hashtable2),
            success: function () {

            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The interesting parts in this prototype implementation are that it uses POST, it's using jQuery ajax not the $.get or $.post shortcuts because the shortcuts don't expose the possibility to specify **processData: false** and that request params are build using the custom *buildParams* function and not via $.param jQuery function.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want your controller to look like?  You could break it up like this:

```
public ActionResult PerformMagic(string[] screaming, string[] mellow) { }

$.get('@Url.Action("PerformMagic")', { screaming: hashtable.screaming, mellow: hashtable.mellow }
```

Or if you **want** to pass a `string[][]`, this might work

```
var hashtable = [];
hashtable.push(["1", "2"]);
hashtable.push(["3", "4", "5"]);

$.get('@Url.Action("PerformMagic")', { arrayOfArrays: hashtable }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely leaning towards passing in the entire hashtable as opposed to passing in separate arrays[].  I guess I could try to see if PerformMagic(string[][] theValues) works.

Comment: @JaJ - I think MVC would be smart enough to handle that.  Just make sure you change the definition of hashtable to [] instead of {} (as above in the second example)